# How can I make the thumbnail title as the post title in WP dynamically?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have now a function to make the size of the thumbnail:

```
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    set_post_thumbnail_size(200,112);
}
```

I would like to make the value of `title=""` as the post title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. If this answer helps you don't forget accept it as correct.

```
the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('title' => strip_tags(get_the_title())));
```

or

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail', array('title' => strip_tags(get_the_title())) );
```

---

**OBS:** "Set Thumbnail" is now called "Featured Image" in the dashboard

[image]

*enjoy it!*